# Removing warnings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, warnings

Usually we write a function in our coding languages and have a return value, but some cases we don’t need returned variable in our code.
when we neglect the returned value while calling the function, it shows a warning which is a little bit annoying. as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I know we can put `_` instead of creating a variable but isn't there any proper method to remove this warning?

Comment: Add `@discardableResult` to the declaration of the function to silence the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add @discardableResult to your function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    neglectable()
}


@discardableResult func neglectable() -> String {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `@discardableResult` to your function and that will silence the warning.

```
@discardableResult func thisFunctionReturnsSomething(_ value1 : String) -> String { 
 return "blablabla"
}
```

now you can call it like

```
thisFunctionReturnsSomething("myString") // now it wont show the warning
```

If you don't want to use `@discardableResult`, you can try this too

```
_ = thisFunctionReturnsSomething("myString")
```